# Recorrer XML en funcion con Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, xml

tengo una funcion en Postgresql que recibe un XML de varios pedidos, Que deberian irse insertando en una tabla, pero por ejemplo NumBodega me trae 5 pedidos, por lo que me marca un error de que regresa varios registros. Como puedo ir recorriendo cada Bodega e ir agregando cada uno?

```
xnumbodega:= (SELECT cast((xpath('/NUMBODEGA/text()',prop))[1]::text as integer) as dato
            from (select unnest(xpath('/CITAS/DETALLECITA/CITA/BODEGA/NUMBODEGA',campo)) As prop
            from tmpxmlc) as X);
```

xnumbodega luego lo escribo en el insert a la tabla donde se guardan los datos ded las citas

Eso es lo que he logrado pero como ya comenté me trae todas las bodegas y me marca error de que devuelve mas de un valor la subconsulta ya que Hay diferentes NUMBODEGA. No se si sea necesario agregar el XML Pero es algo extenso y por eso no lo he agregado, alguien podria darme una idea de como realizar lo que deseo?

XML:

```
<CITAS>
    <DATOSCLIENTE>
        <NOMBRE></NOMBRE>
        <EMAIL></EMAIL>
        <NUMPROVEEDOR>16251</NUMPROVEEDOR>
    </DATOSCLIENTE>
    <DETALLECITA>
        <CITA>
            <BODEGA>
                <NUMBODEGA>25</NUMBODEGA>
                <DETALLEBODEGA>
                    <PEDIDO>32918699</PEDIDO>
                    <LOTES>6</LOTES>
                    <DESTINOS>6, 1, 2, 25</DESTINOS>
                    <FACTURAS>8ED606DC-414C-44CF-974C-07BE77570950, 92FC3687-D012-4DC1-B2CF-4254C7DE6AAA, 9B11881A-A2BA-49B0-9217-D26BC6589415, DEC5CA82-7F29-48DA-8AF7-90DA5FBB57FA</FACTURAS>
                    <FECHA>2019-12-24</FECHA>
                    <IDHORARIO>2240</IDHORARIO>
                    <BODEGA>25</BODEGA>
                    <CONTROL>0</CONTROL>
                    <CTLAGENDALOTES>0</CTLAGENDALOTES>
                    <IDCOMPLETO>0</IDCOMPLETO>
                    <IDHORACOMPLEMENTO>2241</IDHORACOMPLEMENTO>
                </DETALLEBODEGA>
            </BODEGA>
            <BODEGA>
                <NUMBODEGA>12</NUMBODEGA>
                <DETALLEBODEGA>
                    <PEDIDO>32918699</PEDIDO>
                    <LOTES>8</LOTES>
                    <DESTINOS>12, 22, 24, 13</DESTINOS>
                    <FACTURAS>0270F4CB-D5F7-48A2-BBA7-3A79BF96AF2A, 1F13180B-73C8-442B-8A4B-07256BCD5388, C43143FE-38F0-4784-8196-E941BA843018, DCBD6629-892A-4B2E-9394-0EB519D8D13A</FACTURAS>
                    <FECHA>2019-12-24</FECHA>
                    <IDHORARIO>1040</IDHORARIO>
                    <BODEGA>12</BODEGA>
                    <CONTROL>0</CONTROL>
                    <CTLAGENDALOTES>0</CTLAGENDALOTES>
                    <IDCOMPLETO>0</IDCOMPLETO>
                    <IDHORACOMPLEMENTO>1041</IDHORACOMPLEMENTO>
                </DETALLEBODEGA>
            </BODEGA>
            <BODEGA>
                <NUMBODEGA>8</NUMBODEGA>
                <DETALLEBODEGA>
                    <PEDIDO>32918699</PEDIDO>
                    <LOTES>5</LOTES>
                    <DESTINOS>8</DESTINOS>
                    <FACTURAS>0D9ECA09-1AA0-48E9-A33C-33985A52A96A</FACTURAS>
                    <FECHA>2019-12-24</FECHA>
                    <IDHORARIO>728</IDHORARIO>
                    <BODEGA>8</BODEGA>
                    <CONTROL>0</CONTROL>
                    <CTLAGENDALOTES>0</CTLAGENDALOTES>
                    <IDCOMPLETO>0</IDCOMPLETO>
                    <IDHORACOMPLEMENTO>729</IDHORACOMPLEMENTO>
                </DETALLEBODEGA>
            </BODEGA>
            <BODEGA>
                <NUMBODEGA>7</NUMBODEGA>
                <DETALLEBODEGA>
                    <PEDIDO>32685299</PEDIDO>
                    <LOTES>146</LOTES>
                    <DESTINOS>7</DESTINOS>
                    <FACTURAS>5D470EEC-D29F-4DFB-85BD-9E8B08FF1353</FACTURAS>
                    <FECHA>2019-12-24</FECHA>
                    <IDHORARIO>536</IDHORARIO>
                    <BODEGA>7</BODEGA>
                    <CONTROL>0</CONTROL>
                    <CTLAGENDALOTES>0</CTLAGENDALOTES>
                    <IDCOMPLETO>0</IDCOMPLETO>
                    <IDHORACOMPLEMENTO>537</IDHORACOMPLEMENTO>
                </DETALLEBODEGA>
                <DETALLEBODEGA>
                    <PEDIDO>32918699</PEDIDO>
                    <LOTES>4</LOTES>
                    <DESTINOS>7</DESTINOS>
                    <FACTURAS>545AC71B-C803-41B9-B85E-1C34E537989D</FACTURAS>
                    <FECHA>2019-12-24</FECHA>
                    <IDHORARIO>536</IDHORARIO>
                    <BODEGA>7</BODEGA>
                    <CONTROL>0</CONTROL>
                    <CTLAGENDALOTES>0</CTLAGENDALOTES>
                    <IDCOMPLETO>0</IDCOMPLETO>
                    <IDHORACOMPLEMENTO>537</IDHORACOMPLEMENTO>
                </DETALLEBODEGA>
            </BODEGA>
            <BODEGA>
                <NUMBODEGA>15</NUMBODEGA>
                <DETALLEBODEGA>
                    <PEDIDO>32685299</PEDIDO>
                    <LOTES>158</LOTES>
                    <DESTINOS>15</DESTINOS>
                    <FACTURAS>4F37F005-6999-428D-8B3D-598493772DC6</FACTURAS>
                    <FECHA>2019-12-24</FECHA>
                    <IDHORARIO>1424</IDHORARIO>
                    <BODEGA>15</BODEGA>
                    <CONTROL>0</CONTROL>
                    <CTLAGENDALOTES>0</CTLAGENDALOTES>
                    <IDCOMPLETO>0</IDCOMPLETO>
                    <IDHORACOMPLEMENTO>1425</IDHORACOMPLEMENTO>
                </DETALLEBODEGA>
                <DETALLEBODEGA>
                    <PEDIDO>32918699</PEDIDO>
                    <LOTES>5</LOTES>
                    <DESTINOS>15</DESTINOS>
                    <FACTURAS>0C99B12A-40DB-4D85-A222-5EC1550CE641</FACTURAS>
                    <FECHA>2019-12-24</FECHA>
                    <IDHORARIO>1424</IDHORARIO>
                    <BODEGA>15</BODEGA>
                    <CONTROL>0</CONTROL>
                    <CTLAGENDALOTES>0</CTLAGENDALOTES>
                    <IDCOMPLETO>0</IDCOMPLETO>
                    <IDHORACOMPLEMENTO>1425</IDHORACOMPLEMENTO>
                </DETALLEBODEGA>
            </BODEGA>
            <BODEGA>
                <NUMBODEGA>21</NUMBODEGA>
                <DETALLEBODEGA>
                    <PEDIDO>32685299</PEDIDO>
                    <LOTES>163</LOTES>
                    <DESTINOS>18, 3, 21, 16, 27</DESTINOS>
                    <FACTURAS>01A6B706-5020-4CED-BF6E-0EB937293805, 2E9ED76D-2FDD-42B6-9EC4-83CB12560894, 34620B7B-2251-49BA-9D4C-13AEF9F9000B, 34A57BEA-89A0-416A-9F07-46BD8245736E, 70F48225-1B85-4D9F-81BB-B939F9C3C7A1</FACTURAS>
                    <FECHA>2019-12-24</FECHA>
                    <IDHORARIO>2048</IDHORARIO>
                    <BODEGA>21</BODEGA>
                    <CONTROL>0</CONTROL>
                    <CTLAGENDALOTES>0</CTLAGENDALOTES>
                    <IDCOMPLETO>0</IDCOMPLETO>
                    <IDHORACOMPLEMENTO>2049</IDHORACOMPLEMENTO>
                </DETALLEBODEGA>
                <DETALLEBODEGA>
                    <PEDIDO>32918699</PEDIDO>
                    <LOTES>8</LOTES>
                    <DESTINOS>21, 3, 27, 18, 16</DESTINOS>
                    <FACTURAS>0BD6B4B1-5A5D-4D2A-B6FE-3A87D3875375, 1BDD11BE-A9AA-447A-8F8A-C4A0F4842118, 2BA720C4-4374-4DEB-89CC-88A7879CB99F, 8BF3B910-3F43-4CAF-8582-77F93268845B, 9239F8F5-5A71-41C0-AF09-C75DB7D25502</FACTURAS>
                    <FECHA>2019-12-24</FECHA>
                    <IDHORARIO>2048</IDHORARIO>
                    <BODEGA>21</BODEGA>
                    <CONTROL>0</CONTROL>
                    <CTLAGENDALOTES>0</CTLAGENDALOTES>
                    <IDCOMPLETO>0</IDCOMPLETO>
                    <IDHORACOMPLEMENTO>2049</IDHORACOMPLEMENTO>
                </DETALLEBODEGA>
            </BODEGA>
        </CITA>
    </DETALLECITA>
</CITAS>
```

Comment: ¿puedes poner un ejemplo que XML que viene y que necesitas? saludos

Comment: @AnthonySotolongo acabo de editar con el XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

si te refieres a obteter los siguientes valores de ese XML:

```
 xpath 
-------
    25
    12
     8
     7
    15
    21
(6 filas)
```

puedes usar la consulta de este modo,

```
  select (xpath('/NUMBODEGA/text()',prop))[1]::text::int from 
(
select unnest( xpath('/CITAS/DETALLECITA/CITA/BODEGA/NUMBODEGA',dat.campo)  ) as prop
            from 
            (VALUES ( '<CITAS>
    <DATOSCLIENTE>
        <NOMBRE></NOMBRE>
        <EMAIL></EMAIL>
        <NUMPROVEEDOR>16251</NUMPROVEEDOR>
    </DATOSCLIENTE>
    <DETALLECITA>
        <CITA>
            <BODEGA>
                <NUMBODEGA>25</NUMBODEGA>
                <DETALLEBODEGA>
                    <PEDIDO>32918699</PEDIDO>
                    <LOTES>6</LOTES>
                    <DESTINOS>6, 1, 2, 25</DESTINOS>
                    <FACTURAS>8ED606DC-414C-44CF-974C-07BE77570950, 92FC3687-D012-4DC1-B2CF-4254C7DE6AAA, 9B11881A-A2BA-49B0-9217-D26BC6589415, DEC5CA82-7F29-48DA-8AF7-90DA5FBB57FA</FACTURAS>
                    <FECHA>2019-12-24</FECHA>
                    <IDHORARIO>2240</IDHORARIO>
                    <BODEGA>25</BODEGA>
                    <CONTROL>0</CONTROL>
                    <CTLAGENDALOTES>0</CTLAGENDALOTES>
                    <IDCOMPLETO>0</IDCOMPLETO>
                    <IDHORACOMPLEMENTO>2241</IDHORACOMPLEMENTO>
                </DETALLEBODEGA>
            </BODEGA>
            <BODEGA>
                <NUMBODEGA>12</NUMBODEGA>
                <DETALLEBODEGA>
                    <PEDIDO>32918699</PEDIDO>
                    <LOTES>8</LOTES>
                    <DESTINOS>12, 22, 24, 13</DESTINOS>
                    <FACTURAS>0270F4CB-D5F7-48A2-BBA7-3A79BF96AF2A, 1F13180B-73C8-442B-8A4B-07256BCD5388, C43143FE-38F0-4784-8196-E941BA843018, DCBD6629-892A-4B2E-9394-0EB519D8D13A</FACTURAS>
                    <FECHA>2019-12-24</FECHA>
                    <IDHORARIO>1040</IDHORARIO>
                    <BODEGA>12</BODEGA>
                    <CONTROL>0</CONTROL>
                    <CTLAGENDALOTES>0</CTLAGENDALOTES>
                    <IDCOMPLETO>0</IDCOMPLETO>
                    <IDHORACOMPLEMENTO>1041</IDHORACOMPLEMENTO>
                </DETALLEBODEGA>
            </BODEGA>
            <BODEGA>
                <NUMBODEGA>8</NUMBODEGA>
                <DETALLEBODEGA>
                    <PEDIDO>32918699</PEDIDO>
                    <LOTES>5</LOTES>
                    <DESTINOS>8</DESTINOS>
                    <FACTURAS>0D9ECA09-1AA0-48E9-A33C-33985A52A96A</FACTURAS>
                    <FECHA>2019-12-24</FECHA>
                    <IDHORARIO>728</IDHORARIO>
                    <BODEGA>8</BODEGA>
                    <CONTROL>0</CONTROL>
                    <CTLAGENDALOTES>0</CTLAGENDALOTES>
                    <IDCOMPLETO>0</IDCOMPLETO>
                    <IDHORACOMPLEMENTO>729</IDHORACOMPLEMENTO>
                </DETALLEBODEGA>
            </BODEGA>
            <BODEGA>
                <NUMBODEGA>7</NUMBODEGA>
                <DETALLEBODEGA>
                    <PEDIDO>32685299</PEDIDO>
                    <LOTES>146</LOTES>
                    <DESTINOS>7</DESTINOS>
                    <FACTURAS>5D470EEC-D29F-4DFB-85BD-9E8B08FF1353</FACTURAS>
                    <FECHA>2019-12-24</FECHA>
                    <IDHORARIO>536</IDHORARIO>
                    <BODEGA>7</BODEGA>
                    <CONTROL>0</CONTROL>
                    <CTLAGENDALOTES>0</CTLAGENDALOTES>
                    <IDCOMPLETO>0</IDCOMPLETO>
                    <IDHORACOMPLEMENTO>537</IDHORACOMPLEMENTO>
                </DETALLEBODEGA>
                <DETALLEBODEGA>
                    <PEDIDO>32918699</PEDIDO>
                    <LOTES>4</LOTES>
                    <DESTINOS>7</DESTINOS>
                    <FACTURAS>545AC71B-C803-41B9-B85E-1C34E537989D</FACTURAS>
                    <FECHA>2019-12-24</FECHA>
                    <IDHORARIO>536</IDHORARIO>
                    <BODEGA>7</BODEGA>
                    <CONTROL>0</CONTROL>
                    <CTLAGENDALOTES>0</CTLAGENDALOTES>
                    <IDCOMPLETO>0</IDCOMPLETO>
                    <IDHORACOMPLEMENTO>537</IDHORACOMPLEMENTO>
                </DETALLEBODEGA>
            </BODEGA>
            <BODEGA>
                <NUMBODEGA>15</NUMBODEGA>
                <DETALLEBODEGA>
                    <PEDIDO>32685299</PEDIDO>
                    <LOTES>158</LOTES>
                    <DESTINOS>15</DESTINOS>
                    <FACTURAS>4F37F005-6999-428D-8B3D-598493772DC6</FACTURAS>
                    <FECHA>2019-12-24</FECHA>
                    <IDHORARIO>1424</IDHORARIO>
                    <BODEGA>15</BODEGA>
                    <CONTROL>0</CONTROL>
                    <CTLAGENDALOTES>0</CTLAGENDALOTES>
                    <IDCOMPLETO>0</IDCOMPLETO>
                    <IDHORACOMPLEMENTO>1425</IDHORACOMPLEMENTO>
                </DETALLEBODEGA>
                <DETALLEBODEGA>
                    <PEDIDO>32918699</PEDIDO>
                    <LOTES>5</LOTES>
                    <DESTINOS>15</DESTINOS>
                    <FACTURAS>0C99B12A-40DB-4D85-A222-5EC1550CE641</FACTURAS>
                    <FECHA>2019-12-24</FECHA>
                    <IDHORARIO>1424</IDHORARIO>
                    <BODEGA>15</BODEGA>
                    <CONTROL>0</CONTROL>
                    <CTLAGENDALOTES>0</CTLAGENDALOTES>
                    <IDCOMPLETO>0</IDCOMPLETO>
                    <IDHORACOMPLEMENTO>1425</IDHORACOMPLEMENTO>
                </DETALLEBODEGA>
            </BODEGA>
            <BODEGA>
                <NUMBODEGA>21</NUMBODEGA>
                <DETALLEBODEGA>
                    <PEDIDO>32685299</PEDIDO>
                    <LOTES>163</LOTES>
                    <DESTINOS>18, 3, 21, 16, 27</DESTINOS>
                    <FACTURAS>01A6B706-5020-4CED-BF6E-0EB937293805, 2E9ED76D-2FDD-42B6-9EC4-83CB12560894, 34620B7B-2251-49BA-9D4C-13AEF9F9000B, 34A57BEA-89A0-416A-9F07-46BD8245736E, 70F48225-1B85-4D9F-81BB-B939F9C3C7A1</FACTURAS>
                    <FECHA>2019-12-24</FECHA>
                    <IDHORARIO>2048</IDHORARIO>
                    <BODEGA>21</BODEGA>
                    <CONTROL>0</CONTROL>
                    <CTLAGENDALOTES>0</CTLAGENDALOTES>
                    <IDCOMPLETO>0</IDCOMPLETO>
                    <IDHORACOMPLEMENTO>2049</IDHORACOMPLEMENTO>
                </DETALLEBODEGA>
                <DETALLEBODEGA>
                    <PEDIDO>32918699</PEDIDO>
                    <LOTES>8</LOTES>
                    <DESTINOS>21, 3, 27, 18, 16</DESTINOS>
                    <FACTURAS>0BD6B4B1-5A5D-4D2A-B6FE-3A87D3875375, 1BDD11BE-A9AA-447A-8F8A-C4A0F4842118, 2BA720C4-4374-4DEB-89CC-88A7879CB99F, 8BF3B910-3F43-4CAF-8582-77F93268845B, 9239F8F5-5A71-41C0-AF09-C75DB7D25502</FACTURAS>
                    <FECHA>2019-12-24</FECHA>
                    <IDHORARIO>2048</IDHORARIO>
                    <BODEGA>21</BODEGA>
                    <CONTROL>0</CONTROL>
                    <CTLAGENDALOTES>0</CTLAGENDALOTES>
                    <IDCOMPLETO>0</IDCOMPLETO>
                    <IDHORACOMPLEMENTO>2049</IDHORACOMPLEMENTO>
                </DETALLEBODEGA>
            </BODEGA>
        </CITA>
    </DETALLECITA>
</CITAS>'::xml)) AS dat (campo)
) as dat2
```

puedes comentar que version de postgreSQL estas utilizando